# Windows 7: black screen for a minute upon resume from standby

Tags: windows-7, sleep, thinkpad, standby

Does anyone have a possible fix to this problem? My thinkpad w520 has had this problem for over a year. It doesn't always occur, but usually when I leave the computer in standby from more than a few hours, the screen will turn black after signing into Windows. It will stay black for very roughly, a minute. If I leave the computer on standby for shorter periods of time, I won't see this problem.

I've tried, but to no avail:

- turning off screensaver
- disabling CPU deeper sleep
- disabling hybrid sleep

Comment: Have you checked if there are any video driver updates available?

Comment: Yeah, I've checked, and I'm at the latest provided.